# Colored notification icons in status bar and always-on screen

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications

I am trying to find a way to have my notification icons be in color like the yellow icon in the image below. I haven't found an app that does this for me so I am going to start developing my own app (I've never touched android development) that "catches" all of my notifications and pushes a new, colored, notification in its place. My question before embark on this journey is: Is it even possible to do something like this by creating an app or is it something that needs to be changed within the OS?

I have an LGG6 phone and I really like the Always-On screen but I wish the notifications were in color (and even pulsated, but that's for later). My goal is to eventually create something that will push the colored notifications to the built-in Always-On screen but figure I should start by creating the colored notifications first.

EDIT: I should clarify, I intend on making this app solely for my own use and don't need any polished or elegant method.

[Notification icons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzyyO.png)

Comment: For your own app, the latest Android versions will always make those icons black or white. There are some ways to still get your colored icons, but you should neither use nor rely on them. To actually do this for _other_ apps would require you to create a custom rom, since notifications themselves are part of the Android system (AFAIK)

Answer (score 0):

You can bring back the old colored notification icons by changing your target SDK to KitKat but that is very bad since you need to target the latest SDK version.

Comment: Why do I need to target the latest SDK version?

Comment: targetSdkVersion
The most interesting of the three, however, is targetSdkVersion. targetSdkVersion is the main way Android provides forward compatibility by not applying behavior changes unless the targetSdkVersion is updated. This allows you to use new APIs (as you did update your compileSdkVersion right?) prior to working through the behavior changes. 

https://medium.com/google-developers/picking-your-compilesdkversion-minsdkversion-targetsdkversion-a098a0341ebd